# Populate Foreign Key values automatically in SNOWFLAKE

Tags: join, merge, null, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, primary-key

I have **two tables** as per the below structure in **SNOWFLAKE database** and I am trying to **merge** data from the **staging** table onto the below two tables.

Primary key of **DIM_PRODUCTS** table below is PRODUCTID

[image]

Primary Key of **PRODUCTSDETAIL** table is PRODUCTSDETAILID and the **CUSTOMERID** is generated in the **stagingtbale using nextval**
[image]

My understanding is if I **create a table with referencing the foreign key, then the values should populate automatically for that column if the corresponding names are found** but in my case it shows **NULL** values.

Below is the syntax I used to create the **DIM_PRODUCT** table and the **PRODUCTSDETAIL** table

```
create or replace TABLE DIM_PRODUCT cluster by (PRODUCTID)(
    PRODUCTID NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL autoincrement,
    PRODUCTName VARCHAR(),
    primary key (PRODUCTID)
);

Create table PRODUCTSDETAIL(
ProductsdetailID NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL autoincrement,
CUSTOMERID NUMBER(38,0),
PRODUCTID NUMBER(38, 0),
PRODUCTunit varchar(255),
PRODUCTname varchar(255),
PRODUCTcode varchar(255),
PRODUCTquantity varchar(255),
PURCHASEdate TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9),
foreign key (PRODUCTID) references test."manufacturer".dim_product(PRODUCTID))
```

Below is the merge statement I used to load data into details table and got NULL values for PRODUCTID

```
merge into PRODUCTDETAILS as a using (
                        select 
                        CUSTOMERID,
                        f.value as Productunit,
                        Productname[f.index]::Varchar as Productname,
                        Productcode [f.index]::Varchar as Productcode,
                        Productquantity [f.index]::Varchar as Productquantity,
                        PURCHASEDate [f.index]::Timestamp as PURCHASEDate
                        from staging_json b
                        
                        LATERAL FLATTEN(Productunit, RECURSIVE=>true)f) as b on a.PURCHASEDate = b.PURCHASEDate
                                                                                 and a.Productcode = b.Productcode and a.CUSTOMERID = b.CUSTOMERID
                                                                                 and a.Productquantity = b.Productquantity
                        when not matched then insert (CUSTOMERID, PRODUCTID, Productunit, Productname, Productcode,Productquantity, PURCHASEDate) 
                        values (CUSTOMERID, PRODUCTID, Productunit, Productname, Productcode,Productquantity, PURCHASEDate)
```

I have also created sequences to autoincrement for ProductID and ProductdetailID

I also tried a Join approach to populate the ProductID but it did not work out and the code for that is as below

```
merge into PRODUCTDETAILS as a using (
                        select 
                        CUSTOMERID,
                        f.value as Productunit,
                        Productname[f.index]::Varchar as Productname,
                        Productcode [f.index]::Varchar as Productcode,
                        Productquantity [f.index]::Varchar as Productquantity,
                        PURCHASEDate [f.index]::Timestamp as PURCHASEDate
                        from staging_json b
                        LEFT JOIN DIM_PRODUCTS c ON c.PRODUCTNAME =  a.PRODUCTNAME,  
                        LATERAL FLATTEN(Productunit, RECURSIVE=>true)f) as b on a.PURCHASEDate = b.PURCHASEDate
                                                                                 and a.Productcode = b.Productcode and a.CUSTOMERID = b.CUSTOMERID
                                                                                 and a.Productquantity = b.Productquantity
                        when not matched then insert (CUSTOMERID, PRODUCTID, Productunit, Productname, Productcode,Productquantity, PURCHASEDate) 
                        values (CUSTOMERID, PRODUCTID, Productunit, Productname, Productcode,Productquantity, PURCHASEDate)
```

I am trying to find the good practice to load the **PRODUCTID** into the PRODUCTSDETAIL table and make it consistent for querying. Could someone please help me?

Comment: I don't see that you extracted PRODUCTID from the staging_json table after flattening. Please double check your query.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user has raised the same question twice