# Performing merge with JOIN statement in SNOWFLAKE

Tags: join, merge, foreign-keys, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was trying to understand if I can perform **merge along with join** to load data into a table.

In my scenario, I used merge statement to load data into my **PRODUCTSDETAIL** table using data from staging table but I was not able to populate a foreign key column **(PRODUCTID)** since that is the primary key of DIM_PRODUCT table and is autoincremented.

It shows null on executing the merge statement. Can I do **Join** inside the **merge** statement in SNOWFLAKE.
If I can, could someone please help me in accomplishing this. I was also not sure if snowflake could **automatically populate the foreign key based on the PRODUCTNAME**

[image]

Below is the code for creation statement of PRODUCTDETAILS Table

```
Create table PRODUCTSDETAIL(
ProductsdetailID NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL autoincrement,
CUSTOMERID NUMBER(38,0),
PRODUCTID NUMBER(38, 0),
PRODUCTunit varchar(255),
PRODUCTname varchar(255),
PRODUCTcode varchar(255),
PRODUCTquantity varchar(255),
PURCHASEdate TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9),
foreign key (PRODUCTID) references test."manufacturer".dim_product(PRODUCTID))
```

Below is the merge statement I am using to load and got NULL values for PRODUCTSID

```
merge into PRODUCTDETAILS as a using (
                        select 
                        CUSTOMERID,
                        f.value as Productunit,
                        Productname[f.index]::Varchar as Productname,
                        Productcode [f.index]::Varchar as Productcode,
                        Productquantity [f.index]::Varchar as Productquantity,
                        PURCHASEDate [f.index]::Timestamp as PURCHASEDate
                        from staging_json b
                        
                        LATERAL FLATTEN(Productunit, RECURSIVE=>true)f) as b on a.PURCHASEDate = b.PURCHASEDate
                                                                                 and a.Productcode = b.Productcode and a.CUSTOMERID = b.CUSTOMERID
                                                                                 and a.Productquantity = b.Productquantity
                        when not matched then insert (CUSTOMERID, PRODUCTID, Productunit, Productname, Productcode,Productquantity, PURCHASEDate) 
                        values (CUSTOMERID, PRODUCTID, Productunit, Productname, Productcode,Productquantity, PURCHASEDate)
```

When I did insert using Join after the execution of above merge statement the PRODUCTID got added below the records will NULL values populated for other columns as below screenshot
[image]

Below is insert statement I ran after the above merge statment and values got added below
insert into PRODUCTSDETAIL(PRODUCTID)
select a.PRODUCTID
from DIM_PRODUCT a
inner join PRODUCTSETAIL b on a.PRODUCTNAME = b.PRODUCTNAME
where b.PRODUCTID is null;

I tried to do a left join inside the merge statement to fetch PRODUCTID from DIM_PRODUCT but it throws an error **UNKNOWN LEFT JOIN**

Below is the syntax for that

**

```
merge into PRODUCTDETAILS as a using (
                        select 
                        CUSTOMERID,
                        f.value as Productunit,
                        Productname[f.index]::Varchar as Productname,
                        Productcode [f.index]::Varchar as Productcode,
                        Productquantity [f.index]::Varchar as Productquantity,
                        PURCHASEDate [f.index]::Timestamp as PURCHASEDate
                        from staging_json b
                        LEFT JOIN DIM_PRODUCTS c ON c.PRODUCTNAME =  a.PRODUCTNAME,  
                        LATERAL FLATTEN(Productunit, RECURSIVE=>true)f) as b on a.PURCHASEDate = b.PURCHASEDate
                                                                                 and a.Productcode = b.Productcode and a.CUSTOMERID = b.CUSTOMERID
                                                                                 and a.Productquantity = b.Productquantity
                        when not matched then insert (CUSTOMERID, PRODUCTID, Productunit, Productname, Productcode,Productquantity, PURCHASEDate) 
                        values (CUSTOMERID, PRODUCTID, Productunit, Productname, Productcode,Productquantity, PURCHASEDate)
```

**

Comment: Hi - what's stopping you trying a join in your merge and seeing if works?

Comment: Is this the duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69956928/populate-foreign-key-values-automatically-in-snowflake? Seems to be from you as well with the same question.

Comment: Hi Nick and Eric, Thanks for your responses and sorry that there is a duplicate post. The end goal of both posts are the same but the doubts are bit different. One is if there is a way to populate foreign key automatically in SNOWFLAKE based on the PRODUCT NAME and two is if I can perform Merge and Join together. I have edited this post to show the error I am getting while trying to include LEFT JOIN inside merge statement to populate PRODUCTID. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One obvious issue is that you are joining to the wrong table. C should be joined to B not A. Your USING clause needs to construct the dataset that will then be merged into your target table

Comment: Hi Nick, Sorry I have changed the join to happen on table B but still I am getting the error LEFT not found. Could you please help me with the syntax error

Comment: Can you update the SQL in your question to reflect your changes? I assume you've changed a.productname to be the equivalent column in the b table (and haven't just left it as b.productname)?

Comment: Both staging_json and "LATERAL FLATTEN(Productunit, RECURSIVE=>true)f)" used the same alias of "b", I don't see how this query will compile. Please check again.

Comment: Hi Eric, Exactly thats my issue. This query is not compiling and I am trying for a way to overcome this issue, I tried with different alias for each and even then I get the error UNKNOWN LEFT found